# Read each line of HTML form submission Python

Tags: python, html, forms, submission

I'm building a small web app with Python on GAE.

I have an HTML form with a  where users enter a list of items (one item per line). When the form is submitted I want to read each line and store separate entries in the datastore for each item (i.e. line).

I want to do something similar to f.readline() for files, but on the form submission. It's entirely possible that this is incredibly easy.  I'm a complete noob so any help you be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you to try playing with some code on your own and return here with a more detailed question once you get stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want (have?) a text area control in your form, like the one I'm typing into now. Something like this?

```
<textarea name="items"></textarea>
```

When handling the POST request for the form, you will be able to get the value of the text area like so.

```
itemList = self.request.get("items")
```

It will post back the entire text with newline characters (with the escape code \n). The text can be split into a list of lines.

```
items = itemList.split("\n")
```

Aaaand you have a list of lines.

Comment: items = itemList.split("\n")  <-- Yes, that's what I was looking for!  Thanks!